# Parse different formats using fluentd from same source given different tag?

Tags: fluentd

I'm using fluentd in a docker-compose file, where i want it to parse the log output of an apache container as well as other containers with a custom format.

In order to differentiate the formats, I'm planning to set tags in docker-compose like this:

```
      logging:
        driver: "fluentd"
        options:
          tag: "apache2"
```

So fluentd should be able to use different formats based on the tag. But how can I configure fluentd to do this?

The [documentation](https://docs.fluentd.org/how-to-guides/apache-to-s3) says one should put this in the source section (which I can't do because I need two different formats):

```
  <parse>
    @type apache2
  </parse>
```

My very basic `source` looks like this:

```
<source>
  @type forward                                                                                         
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>
```

Is it possible to use fluentd routing to use two different formats for data coming from the same `source` with different tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible:

```
# 1. Omit parsing at the source
<source>
  @type forward                                                                                         
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

# 2. Write a dedicated filter for each format you want
<filter docker.apache2> # Check your exact produced tag, depends of versions. Just guessing here.
  @type parser
  key_name log
  <parse>
    @type apache2
  </parse>
</filter>

<filter docker.backend>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>

# 3. Match and store all
<match **>
  @type s3 
  ...
</match>
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you could also use parse in filter. Thanks!

Comment: For sure, filter is also a modifier, you can parse, remove fields, add fields, modify tags etc.